# Pip show not working as expected

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I try `pip show` I get

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt'
```

When I try `sudo pip show` I get

```
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]
No command by the name pip show
  (maybe you meant "pip install show")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It says show is not a pip command. Maybe you are trying to do `pip freeze`?

Comment: I did that, and it installed `show`... or I'm assuming thats what was installed. The problem still persists.

Comment: What version of pip do you have?

Comment: How do I tell what version I have?

Comment: `Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS] no such option: -V`

Comment: Ahh, that was it! Updated pip, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

`pip` was out of date. Problem fixed.

Comment: I'd be curious to know, though, how an upgraded pip can fix a permission problem: if pip can't read the file before, why could it read it after? Unless the error message itself was at fault.

Comment: when I updated `pip`, I was able to do `pip show`. Before it wasn't even working.